# Problem creating an invoice in Freeagent using PHP oAuth2

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm using PHP-OAuth2 from https://github.com/adoy/PHP-OAuth2 This is suggested by Freeagent in their docs. I've been able to set up authentication, retrieve a token, store the expiry date and then set up a process to automatically fetch a new token when the current one expires.

So far, so good!

I've also been able to set up contacts in the Sandbox and then list these in my web based application pulling them down from Freeagent.

The problem I'm having is creating a new invoice and I suspect it's my lack of oAuth knowledge that's causing the problem, despite reading the API docs and having a good look around for a solution.

Here's what I'm trying to do to create the invoice (PHP):

```
$client = new OAuth2\Client(CLIENTID, SECRET);
$params = array($xml); // See below

$response = $client->fetch("https://api.sandbox.freeagent.com/v2/invoices",
    $params,
    'GET',
    array(
        "Authorization" => "Bearer $freeagentaccesstoken",
        "User-Agent" => "My web app",
        "Content-Type" => "application/xml",
        "Accept" => "application/json"
    )
);
```

I'm looking to send the invoice request in XML and receive the response in JSON.

My XML ($xml in the above) is formatted as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <invoice>
    <contact>https://api.sandbox.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/58019</contact>
    <dated-on type="datetime">2019-05-07</dated-on>
    <payment_terms_in_days>15<payment_terms_in_days>
    <currency>GBP</currency>
    <net-value type="decimal">0.0</net-value>
    <total-value type="decimal">20.00</total-value>
    <paid-value type="decimal">0.0</paid-value>
    <due-value type="decimal">20.00</due-value>                     
    <invoice-items type="array">
       <invoice-item>
          <description>Description will go here</description>
          <item-type>Hours</item-type>
          <price type="decimal">20.00</price>
          <quantity type="decimal">1</quantity>
      </invoice-item>
    </invoice-items>
  </invoice>
```

Sending this gets back:

```
Array ( [result] => Array ( [invoices] => Array ( ) ) [code] => 200 [content_type] => application/Jon; charset=utf-8 )
```

No invoices are created (I suspect the empty brackets in the invoices array are a dead giveaway although there are no errors being given to help me).

I was then hoping to retrieve the invoice number (which I think is termed "reference" in Freeagent) using something like this:

```
foreach ($response['result']['invoices'] as $item) {
    $invoicenumber=$item['reference'];
}
```

But I don't get that far, and I suspect there's a better way of retrieving that when I eventually do.

The Freeagent API doesn't give code specific examples and the internet hasn't been much help for an oAuth newbie like me. I'd really appreciate some help here. Thank you!

Comment: I've tried using json instead of XML but get the error "Invalid JSON":

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about PHP-OAuth2 or FreeAgent, but I did look at the API documentation for [invoices](https://dev.freeagent.com/docs/invoices).

I noticed that the only noticeable difference between getting, creating and updating invoices is the **GET**, **POST** and **PUT** request:

```
GET https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices
POST https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices
PUT https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/:id
```

You say you want to "to create the invoice", yet you use `'GET'` in `$client->fetch()`.

Why not try `'POST'`? I'm not sure that would still be a `fetch()`?

Comment: Thank you, that's a great shout. I changed to a POST. I'm now getting a different error "Invalid XML" although the XML I'm sending is syntactically correct so I can only guess that the format is specific to FreeAgent.

Comment: @CoastalCoder Well, one step forward, two steps back. I'm sorry, but as I said, I don't use this stuff myself, so I have no idea. I was just curious and spotted a potential problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and that was to use CURL for sending my request. Just in case anyone has a similar issue, here's some sample code to help:

```
$ch=curl_init('https://api.sandbox.freeagent.com/v2/invoices');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'Authorization: Bearer '.$freeagentaccesstoken,
   'Content-Type: application/xml',
   'Accept: application/json',
   'User-Agent: My web app',
   'Content-Length: '.strlen($xml))
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result=curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

I also removed some parts of the $xml variable, but don't know if this made any difference. Here it is for a complete solution:

```
$xml = "
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
   <invoice>
      <contact>https://api.sandbox.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/58019</contact>
      <dated-on type=\"datetime\">2019-05-07</dated-on>
      <payment_terms_in_days>15</payment_terms_in_days>
      <total-value type=\"decimal\">20.0</total-value>
      <due-value type=\"decimal\">20.0</due-value>                      
      <invoice-items type=\"array\">
         <invoice-item>
            <description>Description will go here</description>
            <item-type>Services</item-type>
            <price type=\"decimal\">20.0</price>
            <quantity type=\"integer\">1</quantity>
         </invoice-item>
      </invoice-items>
   </invoice>";
```